# How to optimize Mysql Select with count on 3GB table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a table with 37,000,000 rows and 3gb of data.

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_raw` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `ip` VARBINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `stats_raw_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `stats_raw_date_index` (`date`),
    INDEX `stats_raw_user_id_data_index` (`user_id`, `date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

When I try to perform the following query (generated by laravel, that's why it may look weird):

```
select count(ip) as total, INET6_NTOA(ip) as ip
from `stats_raw`
where `user_id` = 1 and date(`date`) >= '2019-02-10'
group by `ip`
order by `total` desc
limit 10
```

It takes around 40 seconds to return results.

How can I optimize this on mysql?

Comment: Use a materialized view ?

Comment: Hi @RedaMeskali first time I heard about it, it's easy to do?

Comment: Yes you can read about them here: https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would write the query as:

```
select count(ip) as total, INET6_NTOA(ip) as ip
from `stats_raw`
where `user_id` = 1 and `date` >= '2019-02-10'
group by `ip`
order by `total` desc
limit 10;
```

Second, you want an index on `stats_raw(user_id, date, ip)`.

That said, it is not clear how much data is being processed.  I don't think there is a way around the sorting for the `group by` and `order by`, so if you have lots of data, you may not be able to speed this query, without more heroic efforts (such as maintaining summary tables using triggers).

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I updated with total rows, I added xxx placeholder when I wrote the questions and forgot to update it. Will check your suggestions and update

Comment: After your suggestions the query went down to 15 seconds which is a great improve. Will wait to see if I get any other answer and award you. Thanks again

Comment: Just do `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT(ip)`.

Comment: Hi @RickJames tried but i don't see a difference in seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gordon really nailed it with the query, so my answer assumes you will be using his query.

A small improvement you can try is to change the `date` column data type to `DATE`, instead of `DATETIME` (Assuming you don't actually need the time portion.)

By doing that, you can reduce the [storage on that column from 5 bytes (or 8, if using a version of MySQL older than 5.6) to 3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time), which will allow more data to be loaded at once, and so reduce some of the overhead.

Of course, if you need the time portion for other things, then this is not an option.

Comment: Well, then suggest a smaller `INT` for users.  And make it `UNSIGNED`.  And get rid of `stats_raw_user_id_index`